# Find the basis $\left \{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4 \right \}$ for $V$ such that $A_i=A_i^{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The question is From **Hoffman and Kunze** as follows

> Let $V$ be a space of $2\times 2$ matrices over $F$ .Find a basis $\left \{A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4  \right \}$ for $V$ such that $A_i^{2}=A_i$ for each $i$

**Solution i tried**-Given that $V$ is vector space of matrices of order $2 \times 2$.so the standard basis for $V$ are $$\left \{ A_1=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
 0&0 
\end{pmatrix},A_2=\begin{pmatrix}
 0&1 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{pmatrix},A_3=\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0 \\ 
 1&0 
\end{pmatrix},A_4=\begin{pmatrix}
 0&0 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{pmatrix} \right \}$$

But the basis which satisfies $A_i^2=A_i$ are only $A_1$ and $A_4$ while $A_2$ and $A_3$ doesn't satisfies the condition,how can i find the set of matrices which satisfies the given condition ,Please provide me a hint, the answer is given in [Find a basis of $M_2(F)$ so that every member of the basis is idempotent](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/931690/find-a-basis-of-m-2f-so-that-every-member-of-the-basis-is-idempotent) but it is not that much helpfull

Please help

Thank you

Comment: But $A_2^2=0$ and $A_3^2=0$ in your case.

Comment: yes that's why i am asking for hint so that  i can use that hint to find that special basis

Comment: I think you should try to replace $A_2$ by a linear combination of your current $A_1$ and $A_2$.  If you find one that works (let's call this new matrix $A'_2$), then you can take the new $A_3$ to be the transpose of $A_2'$.

Comment: @WETutorialSchool but i think that will not be a idemoptent matrix

Comment: I have an example.  Please try first.  I didn't pull that suggestion out of thin air.

Comment: Linear combination of $A_1$ and $A_2$ is $a\begin{bmatrix}
 1&0 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}
 0&1 \\ 
 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$ that will give $\begin{bmatrix}
a &b \\ 
 0& 0
\end{bmatrix}$  but this matrix is idempotent if $a=b=1$

Comment: Yes.  You can construct similarly a basis $\{A_{ij}\}$ for $M_n(F)$ consisting of idempotents by taking $A_{ij}=\sum_{k=i}^jE_{ik}$ if $i\le j$ and $A_{ij}=\sum_{k=j}^iE_{kj}$ if $i>j$, where $E_{ij}$ is the standard matrix with only one $1$ at the $(i,j)$ entry,  and the remaining entries are $0$.

Comment: one think is that i have to check is that whether it is L.I or not.

Comment: Thank you ,now i got it.